What to cover this HVAC vent with?
We have an HVAC vent directly under the sink on floor level. It has just been sitting open since we moved in. It’s about 14’to 14.5 in width. What is the best item to cover this with?

You want a vent cover/register if it still in use.
They usually come in different sizes.
You probably want to search baseboard registers for that size.

That baseboard looks pretty short.  May end up needing a custom solution, possibly a piece of expanded metal mesh cut to fit.

"Under cabinet" baseboard registers do exist. I have some in my kitchen. I can't find a good link right now though.
